# How to iterate object in jquery to check username using each?

Tags: jquery

I have user object which have some value which I am retrieving from db.
I am trying to iterate the user object and check for existing user.

userName  is a variable in which I am assigning the value from form(Which is current user going to add)

```js
var users = [{
  "userName": "amit",
  "password": "amit",
  "roles": "1",
  "status": "0"
}, {
  "userName": "varun",
  "password": "varun",
  "roles": "1",
  "status": "1"
}, {
  "userName": "admin",
  "password": "password",
  "roles": "1",
  "status": "0"
}, {
  "userName": "BigBoss",
  "password": "BigBoss",
  "roles": "1",
  "status": "0"
}, {
  "userName": "Sam",
  "password": "sam",
  "roles": "1",
  "status": "0"
}, {
  "userName": "Sam1",
  "password": "sam1",
  "roles": "1",
  "status": "1"
}, {
  "userName": "Sam2",
  "password": "sam2",
  "roles": "1",
  "status": "1"
}];


function checkExistingUser(users) {
  alert("I am in checkExistingUser");
  console.log(users);
  $(users).each(function(i, e) {

    if (userName == e.userName) {
      alert("User Name allready Exist....")
    } else {
      saveUserData();
    }
  });

}
```

While  iterate through this I am getting an error at console saying:

```
....value:null},gb.error=function(a){throw new Error("Syntax error, unrecognized ex...
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: _which I am retrieving from db_ So you're storing the passwords in plaintext? And just for completeness you're sending all users (including password, roles and state) to the client?

Comment: you're missing a ";" after your "users" declaration aren't you?

Comment: previously  I was just sending name only , I thought the error was causing because of null value so I send all the value jsut to check. but after sending all the value still i got the same error. Once I find the problem I'll remove it

Comment: I don't think using $(users) is the correct way. You're turning the data into a jquery object, which to me is wrong. You can just go with --> $.each(users, function(){ console.log(this) }); .. it should iterate the data properly according to what you want.

Comment: Julo0sS the user value I am getting from ajax call . for the sake of question I have declared users, Thats not a mistake

Comment: talking about "userName" variable,  not users, your users array is declared. No problem with that. Check my answer, your code is working...^^

Answer (score 0):

In your code, I don't see any "userName" declaration...

You should use jsFiddle to show an example, I checked your code and seems to be "working"... check this :

```
var users = [{
  "userName": "Sam",
  "password": "sam",
  "roles": "1",
  "status": "0"
}, {
  "userName": "Sam1",
  "password": "sam1",
  "roles": "1",
  "status": "1"
}, {
  "userName": "Sam2",
  "password": "sam2",
  "roles": "1",
  "status": "1"
}];


function checkExistingUser(users) {
  console.log("I am in checkExistingUser");
  console.log(users);
  var userName = "julos";
  $(users).each(function(i, e) {
    if (userName == e.userName) {
      console.log("User Name allready Exist....")
    } else {
      console.log("ELSE");
    }
  });
}

checkExistingUser(users);
```

Here is a fiddle, check the console... http://jsfiddle.net/x6vyehvk/1/

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Check the code sample to iterate over a array by jquery. The output will be: BigBossSam.

You should use the [JQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) which parameter is an array

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var ary = [{
  "userName": "BigBoss",
  "password": "BigBoss",
  "roles": "1",
  "status": "0"
}, {
  "userName": "Sam",
  "password": "sam",
  "roles": "1",
  "status": "0"
}];
$show = $("#show");

$.each(ary, function(i, v){
    $show.html($show.html() + v.userName);
});
});
```